# Question about using the Cauchy-Riemann equation and showing complex differentiability?

Tags: complex-analysis

Define $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=xy^3$ then we have $u(x,y)=xy^3$ and $v(x,y)=0$.

It follows that $u_x=y^3,u_y=3xy^2$ and $v_x=v_y=0$ so the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold for $(x,0)$ where $x \in \Bbb{R}$.

Now is where the problem is for me, I see that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold on the real line and also we have that all of the first order partials of $u,v$ are continuous everywhere (since $0$ is continuous and polynomials and products of polynomials are continuous) so isn't this enough to conclude that $f$ is complex differentiable on the real line?

On other questions I have seen they have shown that Cauchy-Riemann holds and that the first order partials are continuous and then concluded that it must be complex differentiable (at the points where Cauchy-Riemann hold) yet on this question they bring out the definition of the complex derivative and use that to conclude that it is differentiable why is that the case?

I thought Cauchy-Riemann and continuous partials was enough to imply differentiability (now I am thinking I haven't got the full picture) so why bring out the definition?

Can anyone clear up my confusion?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the details of how it was shown using the definition of the derivative that it is differentiable there?